# Configure different colors for different log levels with logback

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, maven, logback

I have a spring boot project with maven and i have set up a logback.xml to write logs for example for my login to a file, and logs to the console which is working fine

now i am trying to get colors for different levels but if i use %highlight it seems like it automatically uses some coloring that is set somewhere because it does not take mine, ive tried different ways of specifying it

when i removed my highlight tags and content (which is supposed to give me an error?) it still built and used the same colors which are e.g. DEBUG white, INFO cyan

would be really helpful if anyone could help me set custom colors, ty in advance

i removed the code for my file appender, here the part for the console:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{15}) - %msg %n
        </pattern>
        <highlight>
        <color>TRACE=WHITE</color>
        <color>DEBUG=GREEN</color>
        <color>INFO=GREEN</color>
        <color>WARN=YELLOW</color>
        <color>ERROR=RED</color>
    </highlight>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="at.qe.backend.api.services.AuthService" additivity="false" level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE1" />
</logger>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

The console looks like this

[image: the console looks like this]

Edit: i found this
https://github.com/shuwada/logback-custom-color
but it only works for the console logs if i use it for my logs to file aswell i looks like this for some reason

[no idea why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/572ak.png)

Comment: The odd characters/numbers you see in the output file are an artifact of the [ANSI escape color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that are used to color the text in the console output. They aren't supported by most text editors—coloring plaintext is not really something that can be done (hence the name *plain*-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may sound dumb but i think the solution is that it is not possible, since the .log file where i write my logs to is just a plain text file so it is not possible to set the colors of the text, correct me if im wrong